# compare fraction without overflow

Tags: c++, overflow, fractions

I am coding in C++. I am given 2 fractions, a/b and c/d where a,b,c,d are int. Does anyone know of a way to do a/b>c/d without overflow. For example, if I set a,b,c,d as the 4 largest primes less than 2147483647. How would I determine if a/b>c/d is true. I am not allowed to use any other types other than int (ie. I can't convert to long long or double).

Comment: The standard way is to determine if ad>bc.
@LuchianGrigore: this will over flow because the product of the 2 largest primes less than 2147483647 will definitely be greater than 2147483647.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the standard algorithm (compare a*d with b*c), but do the multiplications using something other than 64-bit multiplication.  Like divide your numbers into 16-bit chunks and use a standard biginteger multiplication routine to compute the result.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way that works for positive integers:

```
bool greaterPositiveFraction(int a,int b,int c,int d);

bool greaterOrEqualPositiveFraction(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
  if (b == 0) return true;
  if (d == 0) return false;
  if (a/b > c/d) return true;
  if (a/b < c/d) return false;
  return !greaterPositiveFraction(b,a%b,d,c%d);
}

bool greaterPositiveFraction(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
  if (d == 0) return false;
  if (b == 0) return true;
  if (a/b > c/d) return true;
  if (a/b < c/d) return false;
  return !greaterOrEqualFraction(b,a%b,d,c%d);
}
```

The idea is that if the integer division is less or greater, then you know the answer.  It is only tricky if the integer division gives you the same result.  In this case, you can just use the remainder, and see if a%b/b > c%d/d.  However, we know that a%b/b > c%d/d if b/(a%b) < d/(c%d), so we can just turn the problem around and try it again.

Integer division with remainders of negative values is a bit more messy, but these can easily be handled by cases:

```
bool greaterFraction(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
  if (b<0) { b = -b; a = -a; }
  if (d<0) { d = -d; c = -c; }
  if (a<0 && c<0) return greaterPositiveFraction(-c,d,-a,b);
  if (a<0) return false;
  if (c<0) return true;
  return greaterPositiveFraction(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Comment: You'll loop endlessly if a/b == c/d

Comment: In function *greaterOrEqualPositiveFraction* shouldn't the call *greaterFraction* be *greaterPositiveFraction*?

Comment: @2501: Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: `!greaterPositiveFraction(b,a%b,d,c%d)` equals `greaterOrEqualPositiveFraction(d,c%d,b,a%b)`, so we only need 1 function instead of 2.  Also this could be made iterative instead of recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the school long division method to get the dividend and the quotient and continue dividing recursively like in the below pseudocode:

```
bool compare(a,b,c,d)
    a/b = n + r/b
    c/d = m + q/d
    if (n == m) 
        if (r == 0 && q == 0) return false
        if (r == 0) return false
        if (q == 0) return true
        if (a < b && c < d)
            if (c/a == d/b && c%a == 0 && d%b == 0) return false
            return !compare(b,r,d,q)  //flip it to continue
    if (n > m) return true       //a/b > c/d
    else if (n < m) return false //a/b < c/d
    else return compare(r,b,q,d) //need to continue comparing
```

Comment: The (n==m) check doesn't seem right.  It could still be that a/b > c/d if r/b > q/d.

Comment: Seems like an infinite recursion in some cases.  For example, a=1,b=2,c=1,d=3.

Comment: Added this case. Run till both a/b and c/d < 1 and flip to allow calculation to continue

Comment: Will return true for a=1,b=2,c=1,d=2.

Answer (score 0):

Just do std int division like here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm (see Integer division (unsigned) with remainder). Div int by int does not overflow, and you get both quotient and reminder. Now if Q1 > Q2 or Q1 < Q2 it is clear, if Q1==Q2 then you compare R1/b and R2/d.

E.g. take complex Q1==Q2 case, 25/12 and 44/21, Q1=2 and R2=1, Q2=2 and R2=2, thus Q1==Q2 and you now need to compare 1/12 and 2/21. Now you make a common divisor which is 12*21, but you don't need to multiply them, you just need to compare 1*21 and 2*12. I.e. you compare (1*21)/(12*21) and (2*12)/(12*21) but since divisors are same, this means compare only 1*21 and 2*12.

Hm, but both 1*21 and 2*12 can overflow (if it's not 12 but maxint). OK anyway maybe it will give some ideas.

For a better solution, just implement your own 128-bit (or N-bit) integer class. This is not that hard to do, maybe half day. You just keep high and low 64bit parts separate and overload operator +-*/>><<.

Answer (score 0):

(a/b > c/d) can be partially written as to avoid arithmetic in a number of cases and then to avoid avoid arithmetic overflow and underflow in the remaining cases.  Note that the final case is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
bool fractioncompare(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    bool cd_negative = (c < 0 && d > 0) || (c > 0 && d < 0);
    bool ab_negative = (a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0);

    // if c/d negative and a/b positive then a/b is larger
    if(cd_negative && !ab_negative) return true;

    // if c/d postive and a/b negative then a/b is not larger
    if((!cd_negative && ab_negative) return false;

    bool both_negative = cd_negative && ab_negative;

    // limited cases were a/b > c/d can be determined without needing to 
    // do arithmetic calculations (so no risk of overflow / underflow)
    if(a > c && b < d) return !both_negative;
    if(a < c && b > d) return both_negative;

    int ab = a/b;
    int cd = c/d;

    bool no_trunc = a % b && c % d;
    if(no_trunc) return ab > cd;

    // No risk of overflow with divide and skipping the equal case avoids 
    //truncation issues
    if(ab > cd) return true;
    if(ab < cd) return false;

    // truncation may mean ab and cd aren't actually equal so do some
    // comparisons on differences to determine the result
    if(!both_negative)
    {
        // use subtraction only to avoid overflow
        if(ab == 0) return (b-(b-a) > d-(d-c));
        else return (b-(b-a) < d-(d-c));
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO subtract values with same sign and add with 
        // different signs and compare appropriately to determine result
    }

}
```

Comment: Good catch!  The case where there was no truncation in either division was not handled.  When that occurs resultant integers can just be compared directly accurately.  Code updated.